# Capture data from TextFormField on flutter for http POST request

Tags: dart, flutter

i am trying to make a login with flutter.
I am consulting a web service.
I want to send in the body of the Post request the username and the password from different TextFormField. how can i do that?
Here is the code i've been working on.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:device_id/device_id.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';


class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  Future<String> getData() async {
    final response = await http.post(
        Uri.encodeFull("The route i'm consulting),
        body: {
          "username": user,
          "password": password
        },
```

I want to retrieve the input texts from username and password TextFormField below in here

```
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
        });
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
  }

  String _deviceid = 'Unknown';
  String user = '';
  String password = '';

  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controller2 = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    controller2.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     username = TextFormField(
```

This is the first TextFormField i want to retrieve to send it in the body of the request

```
      controller: controller,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      autofocus: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Username",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 10.0),
          border:
              UnderlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );
    final password = TextFormField(
```

This is the second TextFormField i want to retrieve to send it in the body of the request

```
      controller: controller2,
      autofocus: false,
      obscureText: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Password",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 25.0, 20.0, 10.0),
          border:
              UnderlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

    final loginButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
      child: Material(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        shadowColor: Colors.blueAccent.shade100,
        elevation: 10.0,
        child: MaterialButton(
          minWidth: 200.0,
          height: 42.0,
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          onPressed: (){

          },
          child: Text(
            "Login",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    return Form(
      child: new Center(
        child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0, top: 10.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              username,
              SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              password,
              SizedBox(height: 24.0),
              loginButton
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

See [Retrieve the value of a text field](https://flutter.io/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input/).

1. Wrap a `StatefulWidget` around your form
2. Add two `TextEditingController` fields in your `State`, one for each `TextFormField`
3. Pass the controllers to your form fields (`controller` constructor parameter)
4. Retrieve the values, for example in a button click listener using `myController.text`

I'm not sure if you are also asking how to send a HTTP post request.

Here is a very minimal example:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

  final _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(controller: _usernameController,),
        TextFormField(controller: _passwordController, obscureText: true,),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _performLogin,
          child: Text('Login'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  void _performLogin() {
    String username = _usernameController.text;
    String password = _passwordController.text;

    print('login attempt: $username with $password');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, although i'm stuck in the 4th step, could you please post an example so i can follow it?

Comment: added an example (although I also linked one)

Comment: Someone suggested an edit where the TextEditingControllers are disposed in the dispose() method. While it is good practice to dispose controllers, it is not necessary (look at the source code of the controller), so I rejected it.

Comment: How can I do that if i have a file called LoginUI.dart where I put login UI components and one on them is another file called LoginEmailTextfield.dart where I put LoginEmailTextfield properties and finally a loginBtn.dart where I put login button proprietes ? LoginEmailTextfield.dart & loginBtn.dart  are imported in LoginUI.dart

Answer (score 9):

Here is a full example of a login Screen ... where you can validate inputs and submit the data after passing the validation.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../mixins/validate_mixin.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;
  LoginScreen(this.scaffoldKey);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return LoginScreenState(scaffoldKey);
  }
}

class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen>  with ValidateMixin{
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;

  LoginScreenState(this.scaffoldKey);

  String _email;
  String _password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
      child: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            emailField(),
            passwordField(),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25.0),),
            submitButton(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget emailField() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'ali@gmail.co', labelText: 'Email'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      validator: validateEmail,
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _email = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget passwordField() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: '*****', labelText: 'Password'),
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _password = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget submitButton() {
    return RaisedButton.icon(
      color: Colors.cyan[900],
      textColor: Colors.white,
      label: Text('Submit'),
      icon: Icon(Icons.save), 
      onPressed: () {
        final bool v = formKey.currentState.validate();
        if (v) {
          formKey.currentState.save();
          _performLogin();
          print('object');
        }
    },);
  }

  void _performLogin () {
    var snackbar = new SnackBar(
      content: Text('Email: $_email and Password $_password'),
    );
    scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
  }
}
```

You can back to the full example.
https://github.com/anbturki/flutter_login_screen

Comment: This seems simpler than using `TextEditingController`. Is there any reason to use that approach over this one?

Comment: Instead of Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25.0),), you can use SizedBox(height: 25)

Comment: Hi guys, im doing the same thing on my example but im trying to have an initial value and send it to http.post like this i posted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70980002/flutter-use-variable-created-inside-future-builder-outside-of-the-build-method